# regex pattern findall and search giving different reason inspite of same pattern

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have a string of pattern {{Start date|2005|8|29}}
Now I want to extract 2005,8, 29 as three separate elements.
Hence the regexp I used: re.findall('([0-9])+',str)
this is giving me 5,8 and 9 instead of 2005, 8, 29
Using same pattern when I tried search method re.search('([0-9])+',str).group()
then I got the first element as 2005.
Why there is difference between these 2 method's output. When should be the regex for my current date pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short: you meant `'([0-9]+)'`, not `'([0-9])+'`.

Details: Every pair of parens determines a group. If, in a single attempt to match, the group is captured multiple times, only the last capture is reported.

In particular, when you called this re against the string, it matched all of `"2005"` on the first go round, because `([0-9])` portion matched `'2'`, then `'0'`, then `'0'`, then `'5'`, before it couldn't match any more. So it matched all of `"2005"`, but the group itself only reported the last match for that subexpression: `'5'`.

In comparison, later you tried `re.search` with the group method. The group method returns the substring matched by *the entire regexp*, [not the first group](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group). So it returned all of `"2005"`. Try calling `.group(1)` instead to see the difference.